# Maximizing $cov(X,Y)$ for given $F_X, F_Y$

Tags: probability, optimization, covariance

Given $F_X$ and $F_Y$ of zero mean and unit variance, what is the maximum value for $cov(X,Y)$? Is it simply $$\rho_{max}=E(F_X^{-1}(U)\cdot F_Y^{-1}(U))$$
for a standard uniform $U$? Is there an alternative representation?

Comment: If you speak of a maximum then there should be a parameter that can vary. Don't you mean 'arbitrary $X$ and $Y$ of zero mean and unit variance', rather than 'given'?

Comment: @Jus Marginals of $X$ and $Y$ are fixed. Their joint distribution is allowed to vary.

Comment: I am not sure what your notations mean, but you would probably want to make $X$ and $Y$ deterministically dependent by a nondecreasing real function. In the simple case where $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed the maximum is reached for $X=Y.$ If $X$ is standard normal and $Y$ is concentrated on $\{-1,1\}$ put $Y=\hbox{sign}(X)$. For continuous variables write $\xi$ an $\upsilon$ for the cumulative distribution functions, then the desired nondecreasing function would be $Y=\upsilon^{-1}(\xi(X)).$

Comment: @Jus That's exactly what I did for $\rho_{max}$ as $F_X$ is cdf of $X$ and my choice of form is influenced by the problem of actually generating such $X$ and $Y$. Can you prove optimality?

Comment: I was going to try some variational approach in the case of smooth densities but even the "optimum" is nonsmooth, being concentrated on a curve in the (x,y)-plane. I am going to let it rest for a while, don't mind if you take back the upvote until I come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is given and $Y$ is allowed to vary over all variables of zero mean and unit covariance, then the maximum covariance is reached for $X=Y,$ i.e., covariance 1.

The covariance of two zero-mean variables is really the inner product of two vectors in a Hilbert space, and your question is about the maximum of the inner product of two unit vectors.